# Music playing in background HTML

Tags: html, css, mp3

I currently have a website with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ProximityMC.com</title>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logo"><img src="http://cravatar.eu/head/ProximityMC/500.png" alt="ProximityMC" /></div>
        </div>
        <audio loop autoplay>
            <source src="mmm_yeah.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's okay but I am looking to put some other music on there so once the first song is played then the second one starts etc.

Many Thanks

Comment: Having music on autoplay is a _very_ bad idea. Your users will hate you. Having no button to turn it off (without it restarting after each navigation) is even worse. Not only is it rude to people who would rather listen to their own music, it also wastes the bandwidth of people connected though mobile.

Comment: No. It's just a website to listen to a little bit of music whilst playing a game. Nothing else

Answer (score 0):

You must write

```
<audio controls="controls">
     <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
     <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
     Your browser does not support the audio elemet.
 </audio>
```